# How can you use a Gmail script to attach more than one image at a time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up a Google Sheet with some data to **email images**. I have the code I found online working below to send a single image attachment but I would like to send more than one image at a time if it is possible.

How could I change the code below to work with **multiple images**?  I'm totally new to this and like I said just found this code online.  I have no idea what I'm doing and surprised myself getting this part to work.  Any help getting multiple images to work?

```
 function emailImage(){
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
   // Fetch the range of cells
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)  
   var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var subject = row[1];       // Second column
    var message = row[2];       // Third column
    var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[3]).getBlob();   // Fourth column
    var emailSent = row[4];     // Fifth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [image]});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attachments` property in the `advanced options` parameter takes an `[`array`]` of blobs, so you can use something like this to attach multiple images:

`MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {attachments: [image1, image2, image3]});`

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).